# Black Screen appears behind the dialog in android in some devices (I.e. honor tab)

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog

[image]I am showing an alert dialog on button click.It is working fine in all devices.But in my honor device when dialog appears the content behind the dialog disappears and it shows only black screen behind the dialog.

Here is my style for dialog

```
<style name="AlertStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
</style>
```

Here is my code to show dialog.

```
public void show(String message, String txtPositiveButton){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity,R.style.AlertStyle);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setTitle("Information");

        builder.setPositiveButton(txtPositiveButton, positivecallback);
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (dismisscallback != null)
                    dismisscallback.onDismiss(null);
            }
        });


        mDialog = builder.create();
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();

        mDialog.getButton(mDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.themecolor2));
        mDialog.getButton(mDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mActivity, R.color.themecolor2));
    }
```

Comment: Where is style???

Comment: Where is your style ?

Comment: I have updated my style and also attached a screenshot